# how to replace 'abc' to 'a\0\0c'

Tags: php, regex

how to replace 'abc' to 'a\0\0c'

the following code is fail and give output 'ac'

```
<?php
 $input = 'abc';
 $pattern = '/b/i';
 $replace = "\\0\\0";
 $output = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $input);
 echo $output;
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

When in doubt add more backslashes:

```
$replace = '\\\\0\\\\0';
```

The first level of escaping is for the PHP string parser.  Both single quotes and double quotes interpret `\\` as `\`.  The next level is for the regex parser.

So PHP sees:

```
\\\\0\\\\0
```

which it interprets as:

```
\\0\\0
```

which the regex parser interprets as the literal string:

```
\0\0
```

Comment: +1, i was just toooo slow...Also @OP: gives the example in the php docs - http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$replace = '\\0\\0';
```

?

Comment: output will give  

"abbc"

not a expected value

Comment: Have you tried a different `$replace` string? Is it just a problem with your wanting to insert `\0\0`, or is something drastically broken somewhere else?

Comment: i have tried it, it work for other string, but i need to replace with \0\0, php give the strange output

Answer (score 0):

here's a "neater" another way without those extra slashes

```
$string="abc";
$s = split("[bB]",$string);
print_r( implode('\0\0' , $s) );
```